# How to return all values of String from while loop in java?

Tags: java, file, jframe

I'm making a slideshow class and I need to return all values (of type String) from a list (with elements of type File). I'm using File[counter].getAbsolutePath() to get the String I will need later. However, I need to obtain all values of the paths that go through File.

```
public String getFilesFromDirectory(String path) {

    File thisDirectory = new File(path);
    File[] listDirFiles = thisDirectory.listFiles()
    while (count < listDirFiles.length-1) 

        if(listDirFiles[count].isFile() || listDirFiles[count].isDirectory() || listDirFiles[count].isHidden()){
            count++;
            System.out.println(listDirFiles[count].getAbsolutePath());
    }

    return listDirFiles[count].getAbsolutePath();
```

count is at 0

in the if statement, i want to return all the listDirFiles[count].getAbsolutePath(), but the problem is what is after the if statement. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you right you want to return all absolute paths of available files inside your directory.

So I would recommend to return a list of Strings `List<String>` instead of a single String. Then your code should look like this:

```
public List<String> getFilesFromDirectory(String path) {

    List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    File thisDirectory = new File(path);
    File[] listDirFiles = thisDirectory.listFiles()

    // i would choose a for each loop for this instead of while...
    for(File file : listDirFiles) {
        if(file.isFile() || file.isDirectory() || file.isHidden()) {
            // add the path to the list
            filePaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    return filePaths;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over your "listDirFiles", get de String and save in collection(List/Set/Array) of strings and return that collection.

Example:

```
List<String> filesPath = new ArrayList<>();
for(int x=0; x<listDirFiles.lenght; x++){
   filesPath.add(listDirFiles[x].getAbsolutePath());

}

return filesPath;
```

You also could use Lambda Expressions, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html